# normal vector condition on 1 component

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If you have two normal random variables $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ possibly correlated namely 
you have a multivariate normal distribution $Z= (Z_1, Z_2)$

What is the conditional distribution $(Z_1|Z_2 =a)$?

It should be again normal but what are the corresponding parameters of the resulting 
normal distribution how to find them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If $(Z_1, Z_2)$ is multivariate normal, then $Z_1 | Z_2$ is normal. This wikipedia article shows you how to find conditional distributions:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution

Scroll down to the Conditional distributions section.

This only applies if $(Z_1, Z_2)$ is multivariate normal by the way. Not all pairs of normal variables are multivariate.